# Blocks appearing inside the Content Nodes(Article)

Tags: views, nodes, blocks

I have added two blocks in my content page such as Most Popular block and Related Contents. I have also arranged these blocks to be appear in the lower in the Content section inside the Blocks. But, these blocks are appearing inside the articles after the Title field and then the main content of the article gets displayed as [Here](http://www.articleback.com/cooking-recipes/how-cook-chicken-biriyani) I would like to display these two blocks after end of the article(i.e after the comment). It would be great if somebody can help me out???

I have reordered it already in the following order Under Content in the Block settings:
Main page content
View: Most Popular:
View: Related Contents
But Still these two blocks embedded inside the content.

Comment: Have you tried to move the blocks to another block region? Does it have the same effect?

Comment: I could able to move the block to sidebar region. But i want this block to present after the end of comments of the node.I have region named content. Then, below that region named Postscript first, second, third and fourth. Do i need to add any other region below the Content region???

Comment: try and move your block from content into 'Postscript first' and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: As you said, i moved this block to Postscript first. Its going to left side. Since there are 4 regions as Postscript. Is there any possibility for me to merge Postscript second and third region so that i can move this block there which may give a solution for me.

Comment: Try and move it back to content. If that does not work then keep it in 'Postscript first' and give the region a prefix of 3 columns. This is only a workaround.

Comment: Thats fine. I moved this block to 'Postscript Second' but its aligned vertically. Anyway its looks good. Thank you so much for your suggestions.